# Multiple logins from same user with different roles

Tags: razor, blazor-server-side

My Blazor Server app uses authentication. We have two roles: Attendee and Supervisor.

To handle the authentication, I use this:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
{

    private readonly ProtectedSessionStorage _browserStorage;
    private readonly ClaimsPrincipal _anonymous = new(new ClaimsIdentity());

    public CustomAuthenticationStateProvider(ProtectedSessionStorage protectedBrowserStorage)
    {
        _browserStorage = protectedBrowserStorage;
    }

    public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            var userSessionStorageResult = await _browserStorage.GetAsync<UserSession>("UserSession");
            var userSession = userSessionStorageResult.Success ? userSessionStorageResult.Value : null;

            if (userSession == null)
            {
                return await Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(_anonymous));
            }

            var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim>
            {
                new(ClaimTypes.GivenName, userSession.FirstName!),
                new(ClaimTypes.Name, userSession.FullName!),
                new(ClaimTypes.Email, userSession.Email!),
                new(ClaimTypes.Role, userSession.UserType!),
            }, "CustomAuth"));

            return await Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(claimsPrincipal));
        }
        catch
        {
            return await Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(_anonymous));
        }
    }

    public async Task UpdateAuthenticationState(UserSession? userSession)
    {
        ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal;

        if (userSession != null)
        {
            await _browserStorage.SetAsync("UserSession", userSession);

            claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim>
            {
                new(ClaimTypes.GivenName, userSession.FirstName!),
                new(ClaimTypes.Name, userSession.FullName!),
                new(ClaimTypes.Email, userSession.Email!),
                new(ClaimTypes.Role, userSession.UserRole!)
            }));
        }
        else
        {
            await _browserStorage.DeleteAsync("UserSession");
            claimsPrincipal = _anonymous;
        }

        NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(claimsPrincipal)));
    }
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, CustomAuthenticationStateProvider>();
```

That works as expected, but what if I want a user to be logged in with both roles at a time?
Often the supervisors have separate Attendee-accounts for test purposes, but when they are logged in as Supervisor and then log in as Attendee, they're at the same time logged out as Supervisor (because the UserSession is overwritten).

I have tried to fix this by adding the role name to the UserSession key like this:

```
    public async Task UpdateAuthenticationState(UserSession? userSession, string? userRole)
    {
        ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal;

        if (userSession != null)
        {
            await _browserStorage.SetAsync("UserSession" + userRole, userSession);

            claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim>
            {
                new(ClaimTypes.GivenName, userSession.FirstName!),
                new(ClaimTypes.Name, userSession.FullName!),
                new(ClaimTypes.Email, userSession.Email!),
                new(ClaimTypes.Role, userSession.UserRole!)
            }));
        }
        else
        {
            await _browserStorage.DeleteAsync("UserSession" + userRole);
            claimsPrincipal = _anonymous;
        }

        NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(claimsPrincipal)));
    }
}
```

I believe that could work, but how should I change `GetAuthenticationStateAsync()` as it is looking for `UserSession`?

Comment: Have you considered using Policy Based Authorization, it's far more flexible that Role based?  You can have three policies: Attendee, Supervisor and SupervisorAndAttendee.   If you aren't sure how to do it I can probably put together some demo code for you.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis I have not. I rarely use policies because my needs are typically more than true/false. I always want to learn new things, so I would be happy to se a demo of it. Thanks.

Comment: See my answer below on how to apply multiple roles to a user.  On Policy Based Authorization see this article by Chris Sainty - https://chrissainty.com/securing-your-blazor-apps-configuring-policy-based-authorization-with-blazor/ and this one by me - https://shauncurtis.github.io/articles/Policy-Based-Authorization.html.  Search "blazor policy based authorization".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably also need to modify the `GetAuthenticationStateAsync` to check for both roles in session and merge claims from both of them into singe `ClaimsPrincipal` ? Try this:

```
public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
{
    try
    {
        var attendeeSessionResult = await _browserStorage.GetAsync<UserSession>("UserSessionAttendee");
        var supervisorSessionResult = await _browserStorage.GetAsync<UserSession>("UserSessionSupervisor");

        var attendeeSession = attendeeSessionResult.Success ? attendeeSessionResult.Value : null;
        var supervisorSession = supervisorSessionResult.Success ? supervisorSessionResult.Value : null;

        if (attendeeSession == null && supervisorSession == null)
        {
            return await Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(_anonymous));
        }

        var claims = new List<Claim>();

        if (attendeeSession != null)
        {
            claims.AddRange(new[]
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, attendeeSession.FirstName!),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, attendeeSession.FullName!),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, attendeeSession.Email!),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, attendeeSession.UserRole!),
            });
        }

        if (supervisorSession != null)
        {
            claims.AddRange(new[]
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, supervisorSession.FirstName!),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, supervisorSession.FullName!),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, supervisorSession.Email!),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, supervisorSession.UserRole!),
            });
        }

        var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "CustomAuth"));
        return await Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(claimsPrincipal));
    }
    catch
    {
        return await Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(_anonymous));
    }
}
```

EDIT: ===============

You could modify it this way maybe?:

```
if (attendeeSession != null)
{
    claims.AddRange(new[]
    {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, attendeeSession.FirstName!),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, attendeeSession.FullName!),
        new Claim("AttendeeEmail", attendeeSession.Email!),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, attendeeSession.UserRole!),
    });
}

if (supervisorSession != null)
{
    claims.AddRange(new[]
    {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, supervisorSession.FirstName!),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, supervisorSession.FullName!),
        new Claim("SupervisorEmail", supervisorSession.Email!),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, supervisorSession.UserRole!),
    });
}
```

and then:

```
var userEmail = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "AttendeeEmail")?.Value;
```

By using separate claim types for Attendee and Supervisor email addresses, you can store and retrieve their respective data without overwriting or mixing them up.

Comment: It's not quite as maintainable as I'd hoped if more roles are added in the future, but it solves the problem for now. Thanks. :-)

Comment: Wait. If the user is logged in as both Attendee and Supervisor and I wan't to retrieve the e-mail on the Attendee-user from the claims (it's different accounts so it's not necessarily the same e-mail), how would I do that? How do I ensure, I get the right data? And is it even possible to have multiple claims of the same type or will they overwrite each other?

Comment: I've done some more testing, and if I add the claims with custom names "GivenName_[role]" instead of ClaimTypes.GivenName it'll work. Somehow it doesn't seem like the right way, but maybe it's the only way. :)

Comment: @Mads I edited the answer but I think you figured it out yourself anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your original question:

> but what if I want a user to be logged in with both roles at a time?

The `User` provided by the `AuthenticationState` is a `ClaimsPrincipal` object.

A `ClaimsPrincipal` can have multiple `ClaimsIdentity` objects.  You should be able to use this to add identities with different roles.

Here's a very sinmple custom `AuthenticationStateProvider` that demonstrates how to add multiple identities with different roles to a `ClaimsPrincipal`.

```cs
public class CustomAuthenticationStateProvider : ServerAuthenticationStateProvider
{
    public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        var authState = await base.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        var user = authState.User;
        user.AddIdentity(new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim>() { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin") }));
        user.AddIdentity(new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim>() { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "User") }));

        return await Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(user));
    }
}
```

This user will be able to access pages with `@attribute [Authorize(Roles = "User")]` and `@attribute [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]` set.